# replace infinite loop in tcp listner socket c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm using socket listner to recieve data from client.

Is it possible to replace the infinite loop `while (true)` when the server is listening for connections?

```
// listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10);
```

`// Start listening for connections.
        while (true)//infinite loop
        {
        }`

Comment: _Is it possible.._ Did you tried?

Comment: Why do you need to replace the infinite loop?

Comment: No, not really. You could start a different thread everytime a connection closes, but this is error-prone. What don't you like about the loop?

Comment: i'm using the listner in a winform application.When the loop is runnig  the form stops working

Comment: This is because your are running the loop on the main thread. Try using worker process or a new thread of this loop. Also you might try using Async method call available in the Socket class.

Comment: Or use the `Tick` event of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. However, I'd recommend a thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your while loop looks like this:

```
while(true)
{
    Socket workerSocket = listener.Accept();
    DoSomethingWithSocket(workerSocket);
}
```

then yes, replace the `while(true)` with

`listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);`

then add a method

```
 public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
 {

    Socket workerSocket = Listener.EndAccept(asyn);
    Listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
    DoSomethingWithSocket(workerSocket);
 }
```

Comment: Just one question for clarity. Why have a second beginaccept within the callback, if there's already an infinite loop with one?

Comment: Edit: Did you mean remove the while loop? If yes, when I tried it, my console application quits even before the callback is hit even by one connection. Could you advise?

Comment: @PradeepPuranik Yes replace the whole loop. If you're running in a console you'll need a while(running) quit mechanism to prevent the main method reaching the end and cleaning everything up.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That means I cannot get rid of the loop. The reason I'm trying to get rid of the loop is because my server needs to simultaneously listen at 2 different ports (for normal/admin commands), so when I start the loop for the first listener, I don't know how I can simultaneously start the second one. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Update: Okay, I tried adding the infinite loop in the main function after instantiating an object to start both listeners. The loop has nothing to do with either listener, so it seems to work for now. Though I'm not sure if that is what you had meant, or if that is the accepted method, or at least is efficient enough for production code. Pardon my confusions as I'm just getting started with socket programming.

Comment: @PradeepPuranik Yep, that's exactly what I meant. It's common practise to have a control/main loop and run everything else async. Normally your main loop will do stuff like update UI and read user commands but it doesn't have to. You should probably allow it break if the user types `q` or something though